# MySQL Multiple Select Ambiguous Results

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin, where-clause, dml

Using phpMyAdmin 5.1.44 to experiment with DML commands.

I've been following tutorials on-line.

```
SELECT book.b_isbn, publisher.p_name FROM 'book', 'publisher' WHERE book.b_title='DSA'
```

**Table 1**

```
book

b_id(PK)    b_isbn     b_title   p_id(FK)
-----------------------------------------
1           12345      DSA       1
2           23456      SD        1
3           34567      CSP       2
```

**Table 2**

```
publisher

p_id(PK)    p_name
--------------------
1           Fred
2           John
```

**Expected Results**

```
b_isbn      p_name
---------------------
12345       Fred
```

**Actual Results**

```
b_isbn      p_name
----------------------
12345       Fred
34567       John
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL how to join the tables together (without which it just matches every book to every publisher) - use any one of:

1. add `AND publisher.p_id = book.p_id` to your `WHERE` clause;
2. tell MySQL to join `ON` that condition / `USING` that column;

   ```
   ... FROM book JOIN publisher ON publisher.p_id = book.p_id WHERE ...
   ```

   or

   ```
   ... FROM book JOIN publisher USING (p_id) WHERE ...
   ```
3. use a `NATURAL JOIN` to have MySQL guess that's what you want based on the column names.

   ```
   ... FROM book NATURAL JOIN publisher WHERE ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the fk to the pk key in the where statement

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    book, publisher
WHERE
    book.p_id=publisher.p_id
    AND book.b_title='DSA'
```

Or even better use `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   book
   JOIN publisher
     ON book.p_id=publisher.p_id
WHERE
   book.b_title='DSA'
```

Or if you are not sure if there is a corresponding value then use a `left join`. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   book
   LEFT JOIN publisher
     ON book.p_id=publisher.p_id
WHERE
   book.b_title='DSA'
```